# Calculating Conservation of Each Position in a Sequence Alignment

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to calculate the conservation of each amino acid position in a multiple sequence alignment. I'm using "msa" from BioConductor to perform the analysis. Through this I perform a multiple sequence alignment using ClustalW. This gives me an alignment similar to ...

```
[1] FEYLKLLGKGTFGKVILVKEKATG...KKDPKQRLGGGSEDAKEIMQHRFF
[2] FDYLKLLGKGTFGKVILVREKATG...KKDPKQRLGGGPSDAKEVMEHRFF
[3] FDYLKLLGKGTFGKVILVREKASG...IKDPNKRLGGGPDDAKEIMRHSFF
[4] FIFMEVLGSGAFSEVFLVKQRLTG...EKDPNERY-----TCEKALSHPWI
[5] YRLEKTLGKGQTGLVKLGVHCVTC...EVDAARRL-----TLEHIQKHIWY
[6] ITMKHKLGGGQYGEVYEGVWKKYS...QWNPSDRP-----SFAEIHQAF--
...
```

I know ClustalW uses BLOSUM80 matrix in it's calculations, but I can't find an argument that allows this command to  print the conservation at each position.
The closest I've found is a conservation matrix output which looks a little like ...

```
    v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 ...
-   2  2  1  0  0
A   0  1  0  1  0
C   0  0  0  0  0
D   0  2  0  1  0 
E   0  1  0  1  10
F   4  0  2  0  0
...
```

Is there a way of using this information, combined with the BLOSUM80 pairwise matrix to calculate a sum of pairs score for each aligned position of the alignment??

Thanks for any help or advice that you can offer.

Best wishes,

Natalie

Comment: Check the Mega Software, there you can find lot of distances, for calculating the Sum Of Pairs, you just need to take a grasp on the algorithm, and implement it yourself, its not hard, just a triple loop, i can show you the code of a C# implementation i have, if you need it.

Comment: Hi @RicardoOrtegaMagaña - If you wouldn't mind showing me the code for a C# implementation of the sum of pairs I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This function have a List of List of Chars (seqToAlign) of the object, and can score the sum of pairs using Blosum62 or a simple gap penalty constants, please ignore the extra lines of code, i had some troubles with that function so i had to make sure things work properly, and no time to polish it. And my bad english for the sake of clarity.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Score function using a substitution matrix [matrixSub] for pairwise comparison or blank matrixSub for
    /// penalty of S(Letter, dash)=-2, S(Different Letters)=-1, S(Same letters)=1 , S(dashes)=0
    /// Optional parameters: Start, End to manage to score from sequence[Start] to sequence[end]
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>int with sum of all scoring combinations of columns between sequences</returns>
    public int sumOfPairs(String matrixSub = "Blosum62", int start = 0, int end = -1)
    {
        if (matrixSub == "Blosum62")
        {
            int backGM = gap(2);

            //gap(gap(0), gap(1), -10);

            int sum = 0;
            int totsum = 0;
            int k = seqToAlign.longest();
            for (int c = 0; c != k; c++)
            {
                sum = 0;
                for (int seq = 0; seq != seqToAlign.count(); seq++)
                {
                    for (int seqToCompare = seq; seqToCompare != seqToAlign.count(); seqToCompare++)
                    {
                        if (seqToCompare != seq)
                        {
                            if (c < seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seq).Count && c < seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seqToCompare).Count)
                            {
                                if (seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seq).ElementAt(c) - 65 < 27 && seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seq).ElementAt(c) - 65 >= 0 && seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seqToCompare).ElementAt(c) - 65 < 27 && seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seqToCompare).ElementAt(c) - 65 >= 0)
                                {
                                    sum += Blosum62[seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seq).ElementAt(c) - 65][seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seqToCompare).ElementAt(c) - 65];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seq).ElementAt(c) == seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seqToCompare).ElementAt(c))
                                    {
                                        sum += gap("gap-gap");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sum += gap("mismatch");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sum += gap("mismatch");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                totsum += sum;
                sum = 0;
            }
            //gap(gap(0), gap(1), backGM);
            return totsum;
        }
        else
        {
            int st = 0, en = 0;
            if (start < 0) { st = 0; } else { st = start; }
            if (en < st || end > seqToAlign.count() || end == -1) { en = seqToAlign.count(); } else { en = end + 1; }

            int sum = 0;
            int totsum = 0;
            int k = seqToAlign.longest();
            if (k != -1)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c != k; c++)
                {
                    sum = 0;
                    for (int seq = st; seq != en; seq++)
                    {
                        for (int seqToCompare = seq; seqToCompare != en; seqToCompare++)
                        {
                            if (seqToCompare != seq)
                            {
                                if (c < seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seq).Count && c < seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seqToCompare).Count)
                                {
                                    if (seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seq).ElementAt(c) - 65 < 27 && seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seq).ElementAt(c) - 65 >= 0 && seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seqToCompare).ElementAt(c) - 65 < 27 && seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seqToCompare).ElementAt(c) - 65 >= 0)
                                    {
                                        if (seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seq).ElementAt(c) == seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seqToCompare).ElementAt(c))
                                        {
                                            sum += 1;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            sum += -1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seq).ElementAt(c) == seqToAlign.sequences.ElementAt(seqToCompare).ElementAt(c))
                                        {
                                            sum += 0;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            sum += -2;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    sum += -2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    totsum += sum;
                    sum = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Empty sequence. Check your input file.");
            }
            return totsum;
        }
    }
```

Where Blosum62 is:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Scoring matrix BLOSUM62
    /// Matrix is ordered by the English alphabet to compare, on missing letter is assigned an arbitrary value
    /// example Blosum62 structure:
    ///     A    B   C   D   E   F   G ....
    /// A   4   -2   0  -2  -1  -2   0 ....
    /// B  -2    4  -3   4   1  -3  -1 ....
    /// C   0   -3   9  -3  -4  -2  -3 ....
    /// D  -2    4  -3   6   2  -3  -1 ....
    /// .   .   .   .   .    .   .   . ....
    /// .   .   .   .   .    .   .   . ....
    /// .   .   .   .   .    .   .   . ....
    /// </summary>
    private int[][] Blosum62;
```

And the gap function:

```
    public int gap(string val)
    {
        if (val == "gap-gap") { return gapgap; }
        if (val == "gap opening") { return gapopening; }
        if (val == "gap mismatch") { return gapmismatch; }
        return 0;
    }
```

Blosum62 matrix:

```
 Blosum62 = new int[27][];
    Blosum62[0] = new int[27] { 4, -2, 0, -2, -1, -2, 0, -2, -1, -4, -1, -1, -1, -2, -4, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, -4, 0, -3, -20, -2, -1, -4 };
    Blosum62[1] = new int[27] { -2, 4, -3, 4, 1, -3, -1, 0, -3, -4, 0, -4, -3, 3, -4, -2, 0, -1, 0, -1, -4, -3, -4, -20, -3, 1, -4 };
    Blosum62[2] = new int[27] { 0, -3, 9, -3, -4, -2, -3, -3, -1, -4, -3, -1, -1, -3, -4, -3, -3, -3, -1, -1, -4, -1, -2, -20, -2, -3, -4 };
    Blosum62[3] = new int[27] { -2, 4, -3, 6, 2, -3, -1, -1, -3, -4, -1, -4, -3, 1, -4, -1, 0, -2, 0, -1, -4, -3, -4, -20, -3, 1, -4 };
    Blosum62[4] = new int[27] { -1, 1, -4, 2, 5, -3, -2, 0, -3, -4, 1, -3, -2, 0, -4, -1, 2, 0, 0, -1, -4, -2, -3, -20, -2, 4, -4 };
    Blosum62[5] = new int[27] { -2, -3, -2, -3, -3, 6, -3, -1, 0, -4, -3, 0, 0, -3, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -4, -1, 1, -20, 3, -3, -4 };
    Blosum62[6] = new int[27] { 0, -1, -3, -1, -2, -3, 6, -2, -4, -4, -2, -4, -3, 0, -4, -2, -2, -2, 0, -2, -4, -3, -2, -20, -3, -2, -4 };
    Blosum62[7] = new int[27] { -2, 0, -3, -1, 0, -1, -2, 8, -3, -4, -1, -3, -2, 1, -4, -2, 0, 0, -1, -2, -4, -3, -2, -20, 2, 0, -4 };
    Blosum62[8] = new int[27] { -1, -3, -1, -3, -3, 0, -4, -3, 4, -4, -3, 2, 1, -3, -4, -3, -3, -3, -2, -1, -4, 3, -3, -20, -1, -3, -4 };
    Blosum62[9] = new int[27] { -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, 1, -4, -4, -4, -4, 1, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, 1, -4, -4, -20, -4, -4, 1 };
    Blosum62[10] = new int[27] { -1, 0, -3, -1, 1, -3, -2, -1, -3, -4, 5, -2, -1, 0, -4, -1, 1, 2, 0, -1, -4, -2, -3, -20, -2, 1, -4 };
    Blosum62[11] = new int[27] { -1, -4, -1, -4, -3, 0, -4, -3, 2, -4, -2, 4, 2, -3, -4, -3, -2, -2, -2, -1, -4, 1, -2, -20, -1, -3, -4 };
    Blosum62[12] = new int[27] { -1, -3, -1, -3, -2, 0, -3, -2, 1, -4, -1, 2, 5, -2, -4, -2, 0, -1, -1, -1, -4, 1, -1, -20, -1, -1, -4 };
    Blosum62[13] = new int[27] { -2, 3, -3, 1, 0, -3, 0, 1, -3, -4, 0, -3, -2, 6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 1, 0, -4, -3, -4, -20, -2, 0, -4 };
    Blosum62[14] = new int[27] { -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, 1, -4, -4, -4, -4, 1, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, 1, -4, -4, -20, -4, -4, 1 };
    Blosum62[15] = new int[27] { -1, -2, -3, -1, -1, -4, -2, -2, -3, -4, -1, -3, -2, -2, -4, 7, -1, -2, -1, -1, -4, -2, -4, -20, -3, -1, -4 };
    Blosum62[16] = new int[27] { -1, 0, -3, 0, 2, -3, -2, 0, -3, -4, 1, -2, 0, 0, -4, -1, 5, 1, 0, -1, -4, -2, -2, -20, -1, 3, -4 };
    Blosum62[17] = new int[27] { -1, -1, -3, -2, 0, -3, -2, 0, -3, -4, 2, -2, -1, 0, -4, -2, 1, 5, -1, -1, -4, -3, -3, -20, -2, 0, -4 };
    Blosum62[18] = new int[27] { 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -2, 0, -1, -2, -4, 0, -2, -1, 1, -4, -1, 0, -1, 4, 1, -4, -2, -3, -20, -2, 0, -4 };
    Blosum62[19] = new int[27] { 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -1, -4, -1, -1, -1, 0, -4, -1, -1, -1, 1, 5, -4, 0, -2, -20, -2, -1, -4 };
    Blosum62[20] = new int[27] { -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, 1, -4, -4, -4, -4, 1, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, 1, -4, -4, -20, -4, -4, 1 };
    Blosum62[21] = new int[27] { 0, -3, -1, -3, -2, -1, -3, -3, 3, -4, -2, 1, 1, -3, -4, -2, -2, -3, -2, 0, -4, 4, -3, -20, -1, -2, -4 };
    Blosum62[22] = new int[27] { -3, -4, -2, -4, -3, 1, -2, -2, -3, -4, -3, -2, -1, -4, -4, -4, -2, -3, -3, -2, -4, -3, 11, -20, 2, -3, -4 };
    Blosum62[23] = new int[27] { -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20 };
    Blosum62[24] = new int[27] { -2, -3, -2, -3, -2, 3, -3, 2, -1, -4, -2, -1, -1, -2, -4, -3, -1, -2, -2, -2, -4, -1, 2, -20, 7, -2, -4 };
    Blosum62[25] = new int[27] { -1, 1, -3, 1, 4, -3, -2, 0, -3, -4, 1, -3, -1, 0, -4, -1, 3, 0, 0, -1, -4, -2, -3, -20, -2, 4, -4 };
    Blosum62[26] = new int[27] { -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, 1, -4, -4, -4, -4, 1, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, 1, -4, -4, -20, -4, -4, 1 };
```